# Visual Studio 2012 combobox and textbox

Tags: combobox

friends, I have a combo box and text box. I want when I choose the combobox, then automatically the textbox will be filled automatically with autogenerate number in the textbox, "an example: I chose combobox letter" M ", then I want in the textbox to appear" M.0001 ", please its support master, , ?? I am using visual studio 2012

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the text shown in the textbox by using

```
textboxname.Text = "Your Text"
```

and you can simply read the combobox text by using

```
String s = comboBox1.Text;
```

well now the only thing you need is a listener. You can use the listener of the combobox called "SelectedIndexChanged". This will fire whenever you select an element in the combobox:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx

So you have to simply combine these three things. If you tell me what programming language you use, i could give you a short code snippet.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2012 and mysql
when click combobox "h" then the textbox appear along with autogenerate, example "h.00001". please its support and also code

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, you can include the following code in the comboBox's click event:

```
TextBox1.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedItem & Textbox1.Text.
```